# Unable to add new routes using guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done it before but am having trouble adding a new page and a new path to my rails server.

Pretty much, I want to add a new page and then link to that page in my website... but I am having trouble getting the route creation steps to take effect and show up when I do the "rails routes" command.

I have done it before for an "offerings" page at pages#offerings and again for "public_speaking", but I can't get ruby to create a third page using the same steps, or so it seems.

I started off going to the pages controller and adding a "def public_speaking" and "end":

## Pages Controller

```
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def offerings
  end

  def public_speaking
  end

  def nonverbal
  end   

end
```

## Routes.rb

Then in Routes.rb I tried using the same process (Adding get 'public_speaking', to : 'pages#public_speaking')

```
  root to: "pages#home"

  get 'home/public_speaking'


  get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  resources :users do 
      resource :profile
  end 

  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  resources :contacts, only: [:create]

  get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'

  get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'

  get 'pages/nonverbal'

  get 'nonverbal', to: 'pages#nonverbal'
end
```

I tried both the get 'page', to: 'pages#page' and the get 'pages/page' methods to add a route and neither worked.

## View file

I also created a file "nonverbal.erb" in the views folder with the same name.

## What is shown when I do rails routes

When I run "rails routes":

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-225:~/environment/saasapp$ rails routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
              pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)                  pages#home
             pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)                 pages#about
         pages_offerings GET    /pages/offerings(.:format)             pages#offerings
   pages_public_speaking GET    /pages/public_speaking(.:format)       pages#public_speaking
                    root GET    /                                      pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#destroy
            user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                       pages#about
                contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)                    contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contact-us(.:format)                  contacts#new
               offerings GET    /offerings(.:format)                   pages#offerings
```

I do have 2 offerings routes, would that be a sign of any issues?

What am I doing wrong/missing to create this new path? Is there some command to execute this linkage or something?

I expected there to be a new route created (since it worked for "offerings"), however it has not worked and I'm not sure why. I will be repeating this process for 5-6 pages, so I want to be sure I can do it right

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `offerings GET /offerings(.:format) pages#offerings` is being generated in your routes and from where. It seems that your `routes.rb` doesn't correspond for some reason. And where is `nonverbal` route that i would expect to see. And also having /nonverbal and /pages/nonverbal etc..is intentional ?

However i would recommend try something more universal since you want to use `PagesController.rb` to render various pages.How about something like

```
get "pages/:page", to: "pages#serve"
```

and in PagesController.rb

```
def serve
   render "pages/#{params[:page]}"
end
```

and if you wish you can add [Constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints) to route